# Custom null handling with JSON.NET deserialization

Tags: c#, json.net

I have the following JSON:

```
[
    {
      "ID": "Test1234",
      "Child": {
        "ID": "NULL"
      }
    },
    {
      "ID" : "Test1235",
      "Child": {
         "ID" : "Test1234"
      }
    }
]
```

I have this mapped to the following C# class:

```
[JsonObject]
public class MyExample
{
    string ID;
    MyExample Child;
}
```

This has two objects that model a parent/child relationship. The first object, `Test1234`, should have no `Child` (`null`). Instead, json.net (rightly) deserializes `Child` it as a `MyExample` object where `ID` is "NULL". Here's the behavior I want:

```
var myObjects = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyExample>>(jsonText);
Assert.AreEqual("Test1234", myObjects[0].ID);
Assert.IsNull(myObjects[0].Child);

Assert.AreEqual("Test1235", myObjects[1].ID);
Assert.AreEqual("Test1234", myObjects[1].child.ID);
```

Is there an easy way to specify the null handling for properties? This is the default way of representing null values in the API I'm working with and I have other (related) classes that all work this way.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to write custom code to detect when ID is NULL and simply assign Child to NULL. It's pretty simple and should just be a few lines of code. Something like this:

```
if (myObject.child.ID == NULL)
{
    myObject.child = NULL;
}
```

Comment: I have several classes and a variety of properties that all exhibit this behavior -- The one common element is that "ID" = "NULL", so I'm looking to detect that wherever it appears.